# Windows_NTFS ExFat hard drive disconnects after any interaction with it

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, partition

I have a hard drive that won't show up on my computer for weeks now. I have tried a lot, but what is going is very weird. It doesn't show up anymore in my disk utility, and not even in the system informations in the USB section.

When I do diskutil, it appears.

```
~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Données  70.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 299.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            15.2 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.2 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS maxone                  1.0 TB     disk2s1
```

But when I do it again (just repeating the command , no action in between), disappears !

```
~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Données  70.2 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 299.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            15.2 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 15.2 GB    disk1s5s1
```

Here are the informations on it:

```
~ % diskutil info /dev/disk2
   Device Identifier:         disk2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk2
   Device / Media Name:       USB 3.0

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000204883968 Bytes) (exactly 1953525164 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   No
```

So when I try to make actions on it without getting its id, after disconnecting, reconnecting it, I always get an error, that obviously is never the same in function of the action I'm doing. Here are some example:

```
~ % sudo diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk2
Volume on (null) failed to mount
Perhaps some device or path was not found (kDAReturnNotFound)
If you think the volume is supported but damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

```
~ % sudo mount_exfat /dev/rdisk2s1 /Volumes/voltest
mount_exfat: /dev/rdisk2s1 on /Volumes/voltest: Block device required
```

```
~ % diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
```

The weirdest thing is that, I have the impression that, whenever I try to make an action that could try to write the smallest log or move a single byte on the disk, it gets disconnected. At every command, it takes a while, then an error, and the disk is not connected anymore, I have to physically unplug-replug.

Do you think I still have some actions to try ? If yes, which ones ? Otherwise, should I ask for a backup at a laboratory or whatever professional people could do it better than me ?

THanks

Comment: Have you had a chance to test the harddrive with another computer?